# old documentation of wakanda no more consultable?

Tags: wakanda

Yesterday, I reach to the old documentation of wakanda..(v. 10 and before very good because the "search" was very practice )..I had to consult the syntax for one "query".
I set this url in my favourites on google chrome.
Today,i'm automacally relink to "https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main"
the search in new documentation is not good implemented.
the new documentation is not so large then before
Possible to reach the old documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the "old" documentation is still valid.
However, the latest changes appear not to be updated in the "old" documentation.

http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html